# css hamburger menu doesn't fit the page neither scroll

Tags: jquery, css, menu, submenu, responsive

I'm trying to develop a css menu for mobile. I want a menu that covers all the page when opened. When needed it can also has the scroll bar inside it. My model is something like the cnn.com hamburger menu.

I tried to change to `header{position: fixed}` and change `.menu-btn:checked ~ .menu` height, but no results, even if I think it's the right way to change the code....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <header class="header">
                <nav>
                    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn">
                    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                        <li><a class="open-submenu" href="#">Services   +</a>           
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Serv1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Serv2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Serv3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a class="open-submenu" href="#">Contacts   +</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Cont1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Cont2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {                  

            $('.open-submenu').click(function(e){                   
                var childMenu = e.target.parentNode.children[1];
                var nodes = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;

                if($(childMenu).hasClass('visible')){
                    $(childMenu).removeClass('visible');
                } else {
                    $(childMenu).addClass('visible');
                }   
            }); 

        });
    </script>

                    <main>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui dicta minus molestiae vel beatae natus eveniet ratione temporibus aperiam harum alias officiis assumenda officia quibusdam deleniti eos cupiditate dolore doloribus!</p>
<p>Ad dolore dignissimos asperiores dicta facere optio quod commodi nam tempore recusandae. Rerum sed nulla eum vero expedita ex delectus voluptates rem at neque quos facere sequi unde optio aliquam!</p>
<p>Tenetur quod quidem in voluptatem corporis dolorum dicta sit pariatur porro quaerat autem ipsam odit quam beatae tempora quibusdam illum! Modi velit odio nam nulla unde amet odit pariatur at!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui dicta minus molestiae vel beatae natus eveniet ratione temporibus aperiam harum alias officiis assumenda officia quibusdam deleniti eos cupiditate dolore doloribus!</p>
<p>Ad dolore dignissimos asperiores dicta facere optio quod commodi nam tempore recusandae. Rerum sed nulla eum vero expedita ex delectus voluptates rem at neque quos facere sequi unde optio aliquam!</p>
<p>Tenetur quod quidem in voluptatem corporis dolorum dicta sit pariatur porro quaerat autem ipsam odit quam beatae tempora quibusdam illum! Modi velit odio nam nulla unde amet odit pariatur at!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui dicta minus molestiae vel beatae natus eveniet ratione temporibus aperiam harum alias officiis assumenda officia quibusdam deleniti eos cupiditate dolore doloribus!</p>
<p>Ad dolore dignissimos asperiores dicta facere optio quod commodi nam tempore recusandae. Rerum sed nulla eum vero expedita ex delectus voluptates rem at neque quos facere sequi unde optio aliquam!</p>
<p>Tenetur quod quidem in voluptatem corporis dolorum dicta sit pariatur porro quaerat autem ipsam odit quam beatae tempora quibusdam illum! Modi velit odio nam nulla unde amet odit pariatur at!</p>


</main> 

</body>
</html>
```

The mystyle.css is:

```
.header {
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;  
  width: 100%;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: white;
}

.menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
}

/* Next we need to style the menu icon for the dropdown. */

.menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The graphics of the menu button */ 

.navicon {   
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
}


/* Now we can add the icon when the checkbox is clicked */


.menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 100%;
}


/* submenu */

.submenu{
 display: none;
}

.visible {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: What exactly you need to achieve? Full screen menu? or just disable the links behind?

Comment: you're right, full screen menu. I've modified the post

Comment: I just posted an answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `height: 100vh;` to .header ul. jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/r7yeeyeL/

```
.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

EDIT:

Or, (maybe better), JQuery solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/r7yeeyeL/1/

CSS

```
html {
  max-height: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.blabla {
  height:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(".menu-btn").click(function(){

    if(!$(".header").hasClass("blabla"))
    {
        $(".header").addClass("blabla");
    } else {
    $(".header").removeClass("blabla");
    }
});
```

Comment: Does it not display over the whole page? show me a screenshot pls.

Comment: it works, but only if I have the browser at its max size...if i reduce the window it still doesn't cover all the page..

Comment: Hmm, I can do it in JQuery if that helps? In CSS it's not possible to change  parent elements on click or on hover, etc. and you need to do this in your case. Set html `max-height: 100%`, body `height:100%`, create a class with `height:100%` and then use JQuery to add this class to `.header` when you open the menu, and remove the class when you close the menu.

Comment: It is a good practice to post the solution/code as part of your answer (in addition to a link to the working code) - Links can become unavailable at any given time making the answer incomplete and thus useless to other members of the community.